# Condicional vs. Subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo

Tengo que analizar unas frases que llevan el subjuntivo. Así he explicado el uso del subjuntivo en las oraciones temporales, concesivas, finales etc. Pero me quedan algunas oraciones y no sé cómo clasificarlas (¿como oraciones condicionales?)
por ej.:

*(1) **Se hubiera quedado así hasta el amanecer**, callada, con la mano de él sudando hielo en su mano, pero no pudo soportar el tormento del oído.

(2) **Ella no lo hubiera creído de todos modos**, aunque fuera cierto, porque sus cartas de amor estaban hechas de frases como esa que no valían por su sentido sino por su poder de deslumbramiento.*

Entiendo que aquí tenemos condicionales irreales y que es posible reemplazar el subj. por condicional compuesto. ¿Pero en qué categoria se supone que deberian ir estas oraciones? Mi respuesta sería condicionales (hay que suponer una prótasis elidida), pero no estoy segura... ¿Me podríais dar un consejo por favor?

PD: Perdonad si no es on-topic, no sé a quien preguntar, mi profe es muy impaciente y no ha sido de gran ayuda... ¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: +1 Buena pregunta. Estoy de acuerdo, parecen condicionales con la prótasis elidida.

Comment: ¿La segunda no es concesiva?

Comment: @rsanchez: sí, "aunque fuera cierto" es concesiva : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nótese que ambas frases hacen un uso anómalo del subjuntivo. La primera debería ser *se habría quedado así*, y la segunda *no lo habría creído*, al ser ambos tiempos la conclusión de una oración condicional. La primera tiene la condición omitida, la segunda tiene la condición presente (*aun si fuera cierto*).

Es un caso muy común en el español. Del mismo modo que no dices

> Si estudiaras más, aprobaras.

Sino

> Si estudiaras más, aprobarías.

Del mismo modo, no se debería decir

> Si hubieras estudiado más, hubieras aprobado.

El problema es que cuando la condición se omite, en español nos suena bien usar el subjuntivo cuando en realidad deberíamos estar usando el condicional de indicativo.

---

NOTA: La respuesta se ha actualizado, pero para no despojar al debate de los comentarios de sentido, indicar que al principio hablaba de tiempos verbales erróneos en vez de anómalos.

Comment: No creo que se pueda afirmar tan categóricamente que es incorrecto. La Nueva Gramática da muchos ejemplos de la literatura castellana donde se usa el subjuntivo en vez del condicional en apódosis, aunque sí dice que es más común en el español americano que en el europeo. Sea como sea, qué es correcto y qué no a la larga lo acaba determinando el uso, y el subjuntivo se usa en este sentido desde hace varios siglos y de forma consistente.

Comment: Por cierto, en el español medieval hay registro del uso del imperfecto de subjuntivo (aprobaras) en vez del condicional simple (aprobarías), aunque en la actualidad esta alternancia está restringida a las formas compuestas (hubieras/habrías aprobado), salvo para los verbos "querer", "poder" y "deber", así que no hay una correspondencia directa entre aprobaras-aprobarías y hubieras aprobado-habrías aprobado.

Comment: @Yay es cierto, es un uso que se da desde hace mucho, pero ¿por qué sólo en las formas compuestas, y no en las simples? En las simples se ve muy claramente el error, mas no así en las compuestas, pero no por ello deja de ser un error. Entiendo que sea algo tan común que igual algún día se añada a la gramática. En todo caso, la respuesta entonces está ahi: se trata de una oración condicional en la que por error o costumbre, se ha preferido usar el subjuntivo.

Comment: @Yay Vale, tu segundo comentario me ha llegado tarde...

Comment: @Yay te refieres, supongo, al uso actual que se le da a _debiera_ cuando se tendría que usar _debería_. Tienes toda la razón, también se usa. Yo siempre lo he considerado un uso erróneo del tiempo verbal, igual que en los casos que comentaba. Tal vez haya sido una opinión demasiado purista por mi parte, pero creo que podría resolver la pregunta original. En todo caso, me parece una discusión apasionante, te lo digo en serio.

Comment: Nuevamente, no creo que pueda llamarse error, pero es un debate para el que no hay una respuesta definitiva. En este caso, yo habría usado seguramente el condicional para ambas frases pero no me chirría el uso del subjuntivo tampoco. Por cierto, este es un extracto del El amor en los tiempos del cólera. Yo no tendría el nervio de decirle a García Márquez que usó el tiempo verbal incorrecto :D

Comment: @Yay lo estoy llamando error porque tengo la cabeza demasiado cuadriculada, pienso en algoritmos y reglas. Como andaluz, debería estar acostumbrado a la flexibilidad del lenguaje, pero a veces me pongo muy cabezón. Entiendo perfectamente tu punto de vista. Algo que lleva tanto tiempo siendo usado no debería llamarse error. Por curiosidad, ¿sabes si esta alternancia de tiempos se da en otros idiomas? Me da que en inglés al menos no, pero ¿y en otros idiomas más cercanos?

Comment: @Yay ahora que lo pienso, esto casi que da para otra pregunta...

Comment: No me suena haber oído usar un subjuntivo en vez de un condicional en italiano, aunque sí sé que en francés e italiano se usa el condicional cuando en español se usaría el indicativo para decir "ir a" en el sentido de "estar a punto de", o cuando en español se usaría el subjuntivo en cláusulas temporales (cuando llegue (sub.) = *quando arriveró* (ind.)). Esa es la única anomalía de la que tengo registro. En inglés, curiosamente, [hacen lo contrario](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/if-i-would-have-vs-if-i-had/): usan el condicional tanto en la prótasis como en la apódosis.

Comment: @Yay Curioso lo del caso inglés, no tenía constancia de ello. Por otro lado, si no hemos de calificar la debatida alternancia de verbos como error, creo que has dado con la palabra clave: anomalía.

Comment: ¡Me parece una buena solución!

Comment: @Yay gracias por un debate tan fructífero como interesante, he actualizado la respuesta para reflejar lo acordado.

Comment: … chicooos, muchísimas gracias, qué comentarios tan interesantes y útiles, gracias!!! 
@Yay: sería genial si me pudieras dar una referencia a este fragmento: „La Nueva Gramática da muchos ejemplos de la literatura castellana donde se usa el subjuntivo en vez del condicional en apódosis, aunque sí dice que es más común en el español americano que en el europeo“ : )

Comment: @Aurora El tema se trata a partir de la sección [24.2m](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SGhNClzvyzKXjcAw). Hay ejemplos del español latinoamericano (24.2m), medieval (24.2ñ), de España (24.2o), de las áreas caribeñas (24.2p) y de formas compuestas (24.2s). Por cierto, me parece que la sección 24.2x contesta tu pregunta: "el contenido que aportan las prótasis condicionales queda tácito en un gran número de contextos. El marco o el ámbito irreal que aportan esos segmentos no se expresa en tales casos, pero está presente en la conciencia lingüística de los hablantes."

Comment: @Yay y Carlos, llego tarde a tan interesante discusión. Debo decir que yo soy de los que piensan que se le hace daño al lenguaje cuando se cambia el condicional por el subjuntivo, aunque tampoco tendría el nervio para contrariar a García Márquez. En cuanto a la alternancia en otros idiomas, tuve una profesora de italiano que comentaba que había muchos italianos que dañaban su idioma cambiando el subjuntivo por el pretérito imperfecto en la prótasis. Así, en lugar de "se fosse venuto, ti avrei visto", dicen de forma incorrecta "se ero venuto, ti avrei visto".

Comment: @Yay y Carlos, en cuanto al inglés, he visto ese error comúnmente en personas que no hablan inglés de forma nativa. Quizás porque no les gusta la canción de los Beatles (if I fell in love with you, would you promise to be true...)